# React native router flux reset scenes from navigation stack

Tags: react-native, navigation, react-native-router-flux

I have a scene ( lets called `sceneA` ) where a **lot** of data is rendered inside a listview, so after navigating to another scene, the ui become very slow and laggy because `sceneA` still in the navigation stack, I tried to solve this by calling: `Actions.sceneA({type: "reset"})` inside `componentWillUnmount()` of `sceneA`, but that doesn't seem to work as `componentWillUnmount()` is never called after navigating to another scene, so is there a way to reset previous scenes when navigating inside the app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `<scene/>` tag like this:

```
<Scene type="reset" key="someKey" component={someComponent} .../>
```

In this way if you go to the scene above, the navigation stack will reset.

Comment: Thanks, works fine but for some reason the tabs style is changing ( sometimes disappear completely : show a blank tabs ) any idea why this hapenning ?

Comment: Happy to help you. I'm sorry I don't have any exprience with the `router-flux` tab view.

Comment: I add parameter type="reset" to Scene tag, but anyhow, i can go to previous screen with tapping on bottom tapbar =(

Comment: You can see the official document of `react-native-router-flux` about this: https://github.com/aksonov/react-native-router-flux/blob/master/docs/API.md#scene

Comment: thank you, i already googled that beside of adding param type, you should call main screen (from where you no want to get back) with Actions.ScreenName({ type: "reset" })

Comment: This was very helpful. I have a completely custom bottom nav bar and this solved my issue of Actions.pagename continually pushing pages onto the stack.

Comment: Happy to help you.